# event when app is started, stopped and paused

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I want to log when the user opens and kills the app, and when it is put to the background. So far I have been trying with onStart/onStop/onPause/onResume/onDestroy etc, but this is only about the activity that I put this on, not the entire app. So when the user goes from the MainActivity to some other Activity inside the app, I don't need to know, but when he then goes out of the app, or even kills it, I would like to log that.

Any suggestions? (Did I write it down clear enough?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onCreate()?

See the [lifecycle diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Given your comments it seems you want the [Application Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Make a class that extends Application to make use of these (it will be instantiated automatically), just make sure you specify its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's application tag

**Edit**

I see your confusion, you want just oncreate/terminate here on the [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: But that is also only about one activity

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. your link goes to methods about the lifecycle of an activity, not an application? Do you have any example?

Comment: Yes, that one I was talking about. It goes to ActivityLifecycleCallbacks which is about Activities.

Comment: Ah yes, but any activity not just a single one. Anyway Ive added the other link that you'll need now

Comment: Thanks! I was just reading this post, which discusses the same thing. I guess I can only use the onCreate and onLowMemory methods, because the onTerminate is only for on the emulator.
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for, would be solved creating an AbstractActivity.

Implementing the log logic onCreate()when starts and onDestroy() when go out of the application.

Then all your activities could extends AbstractActivity so it would do the log stuff.

[image]

Comment: In that way I would log it for each activity on it's own. I would rather find something for the app as a whole? (And I would have to use onPause, because onDestroy is not directly called at the moment you leave an activity)